# How to extract values from excel (xlxs) to html text

Tags: html, excel, csv, xlsx

I am trying to extract values from an excel sheet to put into my html.

Here is my excel data:

[image: excel]

I want to be able to just grab the totals of each column for example and insert it into html. Like below:

```
<h1> VALUE </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

// First, download PHPExcel from (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) and save it into the project directory. It's deprecated, but there's a link to the current version of it on the page.  The following code is for the older version, but might get you started as it's tested and working

```
<?php
require_once('PHPExcel.php');
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileName = 'test_data.xlsx'; // Your Excel spreadsheet

if(file_exists($inputFileName)){
    //  Read your Excel workbook
    try {
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    //  Get worksheet dimensions
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
    $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

    //  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
    for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
        //  Read a row of data into an array
        $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
        foreach($rowData[0] as $k=>$v){
            echo $k, $v.'<br>';
        }    
    }
}

?>
```